# Third-party DLLs in a website layout

Tags: dll, build-process, reference

I have a solution with several projects and one website.
The website uses some third-party DLLs.
I have to place the DLLs in the bin folder under the website.  This is the same bin where the DLLs from the other projects get auto-loaded.
Is there a way I can place the third-party DLLs in a separate folder?
If I 'Add Reference' to the DLL when it is in a separate folder, VS always adds it to the GAC.
If the separate folder is outside of the website layout, 'Add Reference' never works.

My goal is have the bin folder only for auto-updated DLLs, and a separate folder for third-party DLLs.  [This method works fine for the projects; just the website has issues]

**EDIT:**
Solution has
\proj1
\proj2
\proj3
\http [the website]

The third-party DLLs are located elsewhere on the drive.  I right-click the website and select 'Add Reference'.  Then, I located the DLL using the 'Browse' tab.  Click 'OK' to add.  The DLL is now in the References list, but has type 'GAC'.  Before all this, the DLL was in the bin folder and didn't even show up under references.

There is no option to 'Copy Local'...and since this is a 'website', it has no pre/post build events option.

Answer (score 0):

That isn't true.

You are free to create new share folder and put the third party dll there.
When you add reference to that dlls, it will get copied to the bin (not added to the GAC)

Can you please elaborate the steps adding the dll?

Comment: also, can you ensure once you've added the reference, that CopyLocal property of that dll is set to true?